# Webpack :use legacy global functions in another module

Tags: javascript, reactjs, backbone.js, webpack

I have been trying to migrate a big app(more than 50kloc legacy code)to webpack from requirejs. since it is very old code I have so may global function decalred in one module that I need to use in some other modules. Mostly I am trying to achieve this without any code change, I don't want to touch the code since it is having many functions like these. any idea?

I have file a.js and b.js

```
//b.js
//so many global function like this in many files. And these are used in many files also
function globalFunc(){
}

//a.js
globalFunc();
```

The a.js and b.js are two diff bundle js from weback, and while running the app I am getting globalFunc is not defined

Comment: what's the trouble?

Comment: You must ensure that b.js is included first/evaluated before a.js.

Comment: `ProvidePlugin` should do what you want to do. Read the documentation for it and the other question, and if that does not work, edit your question with a [mcve] and we can reassess.